# did i use infinite wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, infinity

This algebra question is in Dutch and the original file van be found here: [Question 19](http://havovwo.nl/vwo/vwb/bestanden/vwb104iopg6.pdf)

Ill try to translate the important info needed to answer this question.

$$s= \frac{(a+b)} { (ab)}$$

S= dpt

a= distance(in meters) between eye lens and object

b= distance (in meters) between eye lens and retina

additional info: for his left eye $b=0,017$ meters and he can see objects sharp from a distance (a) of $15\times10^{-2}$ meters and further.

question 19: Between which 2 values of S can this person see/ wear on his glases ?

My answer so far:

$$s=  \frac{15\times10^{-2} + 0,017} {15\times10^2 \times 0,017}$$

$$s= 65ish$$

My question:

How do I calculate the other value ? if I fill infinite in the formula I come up with 1 which isn't good. $\frac{big value}{big value} = 1$ right, or am i not understanding correctly how to use infinite in these situations? if so how is the correct way to use infinite?

Answer according to answer sheet: [answer sheet](http://havovwo.nl/vwo/vwb/bestanden/vwb104iopl6.pdf)

Comment: The word "infinitive" does not have a common mathematical meaning (it is a grammatical term). I would suspect you mean "infinity" or "infinite" except those words _also_ don't seem to make sense here -- there's nothing infinite in your description, only computations on ordinary finite numbers.

Comment: Oh yes i ment infinite, because of the 15 and further in the question therefore i "translated" further into infinite which is exactly what the answer sheet does

Comment: Small note: if I'm not mistaken, dealing with infinity in this way (evaluating certain types of limits) is not required this year as part of the cse. (Als ik me niet vergis hoef je dit soort rekenen met oneindig niet te doen voor het centraal schriftelijk dit jaar.)

Comment: @MeesdeVries im not sure tho cause it is in the "examen bundel" of 2015-2016 but il check the syllabus ;)

Comment: @Kevin Oh, then I might be wrong; definitely check for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, after trying a squinty-eyes interpretation of the Dutch, it looks like the question is asking for both the maximal and *minimal value* that $\frac{a+b}{ab}$ can take for any $a\in[0.15,\infty)$ when $b=0.017$.

In other words you're interested in the behavior of
$$ \frac{a+0.017}{a\cdot 0.017}$$
for large $a$. We can rewrite this as
$$ \frac{a+0.017}{a\cdot 0.017} =
\frac{a}{a\cdot 0.017} + \frac{0.017}{a\cdot 0.017} =
\frac{1}{0.017} + \frac{1}{a} $$
We can see that this is a decreasing function of $a$ -- and when $a$ is large the value is close to, but slightly larger than, $\frac{1}{0.017}$. It can become as close to $\frac{1}{0.017}$ as you want by choosing a large $a$.

---

You can't just say "large value divided by large value" and expect the result to be $1$. For example, a billion and two billion are both large numbers, but their quotient is $\frac12$, not $1$.

Comment: ahh isee i didnt rewrite the formula like this, therefore I thought ∞+b ÷ ∞*b would end up being almost the same value (big value) and therefore =1 but i understand now what i did wrong thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm....

Couldn't we say $\frac {a+b}{ab} = \frac a {ab} +\frac b {ab}= \frac 1b +\frac 1a $?  Thus if $a $ is "infinite" then $\frac {infinite + b}{infinite * b} =\frac {infinite}{infinite*b} =\frac 1b$ is consistent with $\frac 1b + \frac 1 {infinite}= \frac 1b +0 =\frac 1b $.

I think your confusion is inf/inf can be *anything*-- not *just* 1.  In the case of inf/inf x b, it should be 1/b.  Assuming the infs  are "the same".

In actuality you can't really do any of this.  But you can do $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac {n +b}{nb} = \lim 1/b + 1/n = 1/b $.

Comment: yea that was my confusion indeed. Thanks to Henning and your explanation i know how to handle these type of questions now.